# php number_format func to change 11223344556677 to 1122334455/66/77

Tags: php, number-formatting

I tried this:

```
$number = 11223344556677;
echo number_format($number,2,'/',2,'/','');
```

but did not get the result. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `number_format` is not made to do that. You can do it yourself in a variety of ways, for example:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(\d*)(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', '$1/$2/$3', $number);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$formatted_number = preg_replace('(\d+?)(\d\d)(\d\d)','$1/$2/$3',$number);
```